# Changing an element's class on another element's click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code, but it's not working. I'm trying to add or remove a class based on a click event.

Javascript:

```
function done(e){   
    if (e.hasClass("Gset")) {
         e.removeClass("Gset") 
    }
    else {
         e.addClass("Gset") 
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<h4 id="test">
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="done(test)">
    Ready?
</h4>
```

[Here is a Jfiddle link showing it](https://jsfiddle.net/silverstarfy/q3eyz5na/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your fiddle won't work as long as the Javascript is set to "Load Type: OnLoad"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because `e` in your function is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. DOM elements don't have jQuery functions on them.

I should note that the only reason that it's a DOM element is that by giving the element an `id`, you've caused the browser to create an *automatic global* for it, which is why `onClick="done(test)"` works at all (the `test` there is a variable reference, and will pick up the automatic global).

The *minimal* fix is to make it a jQuery object:

```
function done(e){   
e = $(e);                                         // <===
if (e.hasClass("Gset")){e.removeClass("Gset") }
else {e.addClass("Gset") }
}
```

But a more thorough fix is to use `toggleClass` as well:

```
function done(e) {
    $(e).toggleClass("Gset");
}
```

And even more thorough update would be to hook up the handler using jQuery rather than using the long-outdated `onxyz` attributes, not least because relying on automatic globals is error-prone (for instance, `id="name"` would fail):

```js
$("#test input").on("click", function() {
  $("#test").toggleClass("Gset");
});
```

```css
.Gset {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h4 id="test">
  <input type="checkbox">
  Ready?
</h4>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Send the parameter as:

```
done(this)
```

And then in the function:

```
function done(e) {
  e = $(e).parent();
  if (e.hasClass("Gset")) {
    e.removeClass("Gset")
  } else {
    e.addClass("Gset")
  }
}
```

There's a simpler way:

```
function done(e) {
  $(e).parent().toggleClass("Gset");
}
```

**Reasons:**

- `e`, as passed as `this` will be a DOMElement, but `hasClass`, `addClass` and `removeClass` works only on jQuery objects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nopes. `test` is the parent. Oh yeah, that's what I said.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Updated. Man I wanna contact you, how can I? Skype?

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you avoid `inline-event` onClick.

**HTML :**

```
<h4 id="test">
    <input type="checkbox">Ready?
</h4>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#test input').click(function(){
    $('#test').toggleClass("Gset");
})
```

Hope this helps.